# Overriding a hooked in function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

What is the procedure of overriding functions that are hooked into WordPress?

The following function in **wc-template-functions.php** is one of the functions I'm looking to override:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close() {
    echo '</a>';
}
```

It is hooked in at **wc-template-hooks.php**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

If I write the following code, the function is then *unhooked*:

```
function remove_default_wc_behaviour() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_wc_behaviour' );
```

But what if I want to override the function, ie. implement my own functionality instead of the default functionality from WooCommerce?

Would I call a `remove_action()` first, and then hook in my function with `add_action()`, or is there a procedure which can simply override the function that is hooked in my WooCommerce?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have done is absolutely correct.... that is the exact way

Comment: Thank you :) Feel free to post it as an answer, and I will mark it as the right one

Comment: It's okay man.... it's nice to hear that everything is working fine and everybody is following code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is the right one: In your main function hooked in **`init`** action hook, you can add your replacement hooked function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'replace_default_wc_behaviour' );
function remove_default_wc_behaviour() {
    // remove the default behavior
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );

    // Replace by your custom behavior
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_WC_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
    function custom_WC_loop_product_link_close() {
        // Do your custumizations

        // add the close tag
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*